# date in php for update

Tags: php, date

I am developing an application that needs to take an updated file.
I create a php page that returns the date of update and in case was more recent than the program sends the file.

How can I verify this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php).